# Solve with inexact coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation:

```
Solve[1000 Sqrt[2] == (702.762 S^2)/(
0.5[1 + 930.132/S^2 + 0.5[-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2]]] + 
Sqrt[-(930.132/S^2) + 
0.5[1 + 930.132/S^2 + 0.5[-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2]]]^2]), S]
```

but it doesn't work. "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the \
system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present \
in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact \
input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help"
How ca

Comment: Focus on: `0.5[1 + 930.132/S^2 + 0.5[-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2]]]`. `[]` is used specifically for function calls in _Mathematica_. If you're intending to multiply these values, make sure to use `()` instead.

Comment: And never use an upper-case letter to start a variable name, as it may conflict with internal *Mathematica* names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerical solve is the method you need:

```
NSolve[0 == -1000 Sqrt[2] + (702.762 S^2)/(0.5 (1 + 930.132/S^2 +0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2])) +Sqrt[-(930.132/S^2) +0.5 (1 + 930.132/S^2 + 0.5 (-0.2 +30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2]))^2]), S]
(* {{S -> -7.12064}, {S -> 7.12064}} *)
```

Comment: Furthermore, I want to use the positive value of this solution as a coefficient of another equation. How can I do this?

Comment: Just take the second part(`[[2]]`) of the NSolve-result or give a constraint inside NSOlve `NSolve[{0 == -1000 Sqrt[2] + (702.762 S^2)/(0.5 (1 + 930.132/S^2 +0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2])) +Sqrt[-(930.132/S^2) +0.5 (1 + 930.132/S^2 + 0.5 (-0.2 +30.4981 Sqrt[1/S^2]))^2]),S>0}, S]`